# Button in google web app linked to spreadcheet while using search menu

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I have a problem where I have taken a script code from [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_search_menu)
and this works fine but the only problem is that I want it to insert a text in the Spreadsheet when I click on it. Instead of moving me to a link address.
[image]

Like you see here in the picture. I have created a sidebar in the Spreadsheet for the search menu and if I have multiple options on the menu, I want to be able to search on that option and insert that option in the Spreadsheet if you click on it.
I am stuck and my head is so clumsy and would be great if someone could find a solution for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is creating a JavaScript function in your HTML file that when it is clicked you will pass the `this` object, so you can take the value inside the `a` tag using `.innerHTML` to your Apps Script code running in your server-side with the help of the Class  [`google.script.run (Client-side API)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myfunction...-any-server-side-function).

### HTML

```
<body>
<h2>Search Menu</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="left" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Menu</h2>
    <ul id="myMenu">
      <li><a  onClick="getTagValue(this)">Java</a></li>
      <li><a onClick="getTagValue(this)">Python</a></li>
      <li><a onClick="getTagValue(this)">Node.js</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  function getTagValue(obj){
    google.script.run.doSomething(obj.innerHTML);
  }
</script>
</body>
```

Then in your Apps Script code, you only need to create a function with the same of the function you named in the HTML file, in this case, `doSomething`. Therefore, you will be able to insert the values you want in your SpreadSheet.

### Apps Script

```
function doSomething(val){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 1).setValue([val]);
}
```

Comment: big thanks to you i will try it as fast i get to it:)

Comment: Yes i tryd it now and it works:) Thx a lot. It gave me some spare time